# How to debug javascript line by line in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to debug line by line javascript in visual studio 2010. i am developing mobile web application using HTML5 and javascript using phone gap emulator in visual studio 2010. please help me how debug javascript...thank you

Comment: If you use vs built in webserver and run the asp.net application, vs will cache the debug files for you, including the scripts. They are available at solution explorer while debug is running. There, you can set breakpoints even om javascript rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript debugger keyword in IE....

```
function onClickRow(detailUrl) {
    debugger;
}
```

When run your page in IE, a debug window will pop up, then select Visual Studio 11.

For more detail on debugging of client side script in Visual Studio 11, have a look on following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx

Comment: @ akash88...yesterday i tried as u told and also i followed d =the microsoft link...i am not running application IE if i amruuning in IE its fine...but i am running application phone gap windows emulator...so how can i debug javascript...please help me